# Pygame .rumble() function not working via BlueTooth

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, ps4

I'm new to pygame. I need to make a DualShock 4 controller rumble via BlueTooth. I know that the `.rumble(low_frequency, high_frequency, duration)` makes the controller rumble, and it works for me, but only when I connect my DualShock4 via USB. When I connect it with BlueTooth, the function returns False, and it doesn't work. Why is this, and how do I fix it, if possible? I am on Windows 11, and all my bluetooth drivers are up to date.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If I add these two lines of code:

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_JOYSTICK_HIDAPI_PS4_RUMBLE'] = '1'
```

The rumbling works, even via BlueTooth. Check this Reddit answer for more details: https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/12twl0e/cannot_rumble_dualshock_4_via_bluetooth_in_pygame/